# Double lines in $X$, implies $X \cong \mathbb{P}^{n}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a smooth, complex, projective variety. How to prove that if through two general points of $X$ there exists a double line, then $X \cong \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{n}$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you have a variety where two general points are connected by a line, then you can easily put a double structure on the line (e.g. by squaring one of the linear forms that cut out the line.) Could you clarify?

Comment: By a double line in $X$ I mean a closed immersion $i: \mathrm{Proj}(\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]/(z^{2})) \rightarrow X$.

Comment: Yes, what I meant in my question was why ask about _double_ lines, since as far as I can tell it is equivalent to the same question about lines. Anyway, either version can be answered by thinking about the embedded tangent space to $X$ at a general point: every line through the point and lying in $X$ is contained in the tangent space, but then by the hypotheses the variety must be equal to the tangent space, hence a projective space.